# My navigate to component URL is opening but I am not able to fetch state record Id from it

Tags: lightning

This is my code:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >
   <aura:attribute name="pageReference" type="Object"/>  
   <aura:handler name="init" value="this" action="{!c.doInit}"/> 
    <aura:attribute name="url" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="accId" type="Id"/>
    <lightning:navigation aura:id="navService"/>
    <div style="background:#ffffff; margin:2px; border-radius: 2px; padding-left: 12px; padding-right: 12px; padding-top: 2px; padding-bottom: 7px;">
        <p style="font-size:90%;">

            <lightning:button variant="brand" label="New Case" title="New Case" onclick="{!c.mycomp}"/>
        </p>
    </div>    
</aura:component>
```

Component :

```
mycomp : function(component, event, helper){
        var navService = component.find("navService");

     var pageReference = {
                         "type": "standard__component",
                         "attributes": {
                                         "componentName": "c__NewCase"
                                       }, 
                         "state": {
                             recordId : component.get("v.recordId")
                                  }
                          };
       component.set("v.pageReference", pageReference);
     navService.navigate(pageReference);
```

This code is opening my component but i am getting undefined for recordId attribute.

doInit function in Controller of New Case component is :

```
    var myPageRef = component.get("v.pageReference");        
    component.set("v.parentRecordId",myPageRef.state.recordId);
    var accountId = component.get("v.parentRecordId");
    console.log("account id"+accountId);
```

I am getting undefined in recordID in new component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since pageReference state gets put into the queryParams of the url, you need to add c__ in front of the name or they will get stripped. It's from a somewhat recent update. Try c__recordId instead.

Original component:

```js
mycomp : function(component, event, helper){
        var navService = component.find("navService");

     var pageReference = {
                         "type": "standard__component",
                         "attributes": {
                                         "componentName": "c__NewCase"
                                       }, 
                         "state": {
                             c__recordId : component.get("v.recordId") // here
                                  }
                          };
       component.set("v.pageReference", pageReference);
     navService.navigate(pageReference);
```

New Case Component:

```js
    var myPageRef = component.get("v.pageReference");        
    component.set("v.parentRecordId",myPageRef.state.c__recordId); //and here
    var accountId = component.get("v.parentRecordId");
    console.log("account id"+accountId);
```

EDIT: Here's the critical update for this issue - https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring19/release-notes/rn_forcecom_general_namespace_prefix_cruc_reminder.htm

Comment: Thanks so much. It worked :)